# When presenting a logo to a client what type of paper should I use?

Tags: print-design, logo, branding, presentation-design, presentation

I am presenting a logo ( and other branding ) to a client. I know that I should present the logo as it will be used, so I will be using card stock for the business card version; and their stationary paper for the letterhead etc., but I would like to print the logo out in a larger format too, like A4, so it can be appreciated better, even though it won't be used at this size.

I know there are options to print on presentation boards but I don't imagine going down that road for this project, so I wonder what type of paper would work well. In particular I am wondering whether or not to use photographic paper, whether to use matte or gloss, and if weight makes any difference as long as it is reasonably heavy.

Ideally I would like to keep the cost down a bit because I will probably have multiple meetings with this client and there will be an iterative revision process and I'd like to present multiple logo versions at each meeting, so overall there may be a good few prints.

Comment: This is pretty much purely an opinion based question. Everyone will do it in their own ways. These days, I rarely print out anything...most presentations are done via email and PDFs.

Comment: Thanks I understand but I do want to print this material out in my case, and I would like some suggestions if possible. I'm a web designer and I don't really know much about paper.

Comment: Which is fair, but there are literally just too many suggestions. It'll depend on the client, the logo, the printer you have, etc. For A BBQ joint, I might create a stencil and spray paint it onto some butcher paper. For a t-shirt company, I might get a canvas print. It's all context-driven. Barring all of that, I'd just get the heaviest weight, brightest-white paper your printer will support.

Comment: "I know that I should present the logo as it will be used, so I will be using card stock for the business card version;" Really? - It is a big diference on presenting a business card dummy and presenting your logo... Actually I almost do not print any dummy either. Print a logo for a presentation on whatever paper you (and your printer) like.

Comment: Ok well I wasn't really having an issue with that part; it was just the backstory, but I understand your point

Comment: @DA01 would there be any compelling reason to either avoid or use photo paper ( i mean coated paper ) - or is it be more or less open to opinion and circumstance. I suppose I wonder if photo paper is something that graphic designers generally avoid or not. I know photographers must use it but is non coated paper better for design work

Comment: @Rafael I think I was getting that from this - http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/44685/2624

Comment: @byronyasgur no compelling reason one way or the other, really. If you like it and it works for your logo, go for it.